# How to convert HTML text to CSV?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this following HTML table in a text file (.txt):

```
<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Basic EPS (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">57.18</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.84</td>
</tr>
<tr height="22px">
<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Diluted Eps (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">56.43</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.26</td>
</tr>
```

The CSV output should look like this:

```
Basic EPS (Rs.)|57.18|48.84
Diluted Eps (Rs.)|56.43|48.26
```

Comment: The HTML you have is missing the start and end of the `<table>` block which would make it harder to parse.

Answer (score 1):

As tempting as it might be to use a regular expression for this, I would definitely recommend you use the Python [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) library to help as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

html = """<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Basic EPS (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">57.18</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.84</td>
</tr>
<tr height="22px">
<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Diluted Eps (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">56.43</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.26</td>
</tr>"""

# Add the missing surrounding HTML
html = "<table><tr>{}</table>".format(html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='|')

    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        csv_output.writerow([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')])
```

Giving you:

```
Basic EPS (Rs.)|57.18|48.84
Diluted Eps (Rs.)|56.43|48.26
```

The HTML you have is missing the enclosing `<table>` `<tr>` and final `</table>` tags, so to allow it to be processed correctly I have added these back prior to processing.

You can then use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library to write each row of cells as a correctly delimited line in an output CSV file.

This is tested on Python 2.x, if you are using Python 3.x you would need to use `open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')` instead.

---

Alternatively, but not recommended:

```
import re

html = """<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Basic EPS (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">57.18</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.84!!</td>
</tr>
<tr height="22px">
<td class="det" colspan="1" width="40%">Diluted Eps (Rs.)</td>
<td align="right" class="det">56.43</td>
<td align="right" class="det">48.26</td>
</tr>"""

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='|')
    tds = re.findall(r'\<td.*?\>(.*?)\<\/td\>', html)

    for index in range(0, len(tds), 3):
        csv_output.writerow(tds[index:index+3])
```